# Fallout 4 - Freedom Trail Code

Tags: fallout-4

I followed the red brick road through out Boston and found several markers with number/letter pairs.

The trail ended inside the Old Chruch where I found the "pad lock":

[image]

Was I supposed to remember the code myself, or is it stored anywhere in the PipBoy? Or since I can't find the code in my PipBoy does this mean I didn't find all the 'stops' on the Tour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should have been the letters on the chalk markings you found while following Freedom's Trail.

If you don't feel like going back here's the answer:

> RAILROAD

EDIT: I probably should have mentioned but as far as I saw the password wasn't stored anywhere, but I accidentally skipped a few when I went on Freedom's Trail.

Comment: I looked at every one and wrote them down manually on some paper. I'm pretty sure it wasn't stored anywhere in the Pip-Boy.

Comment: Pretty sure not every character can be found on the tour, but with what you have and a little puzzle solving skills this is doable.